# How to deal with CSV data misplacement problem?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a problem about data misplacement.
The data shift right two cells.

[image]

My questions are :

1. How to import these data? Since when I use `pd.read_csv`, there always errors as follows:

   ```
   ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 18 fields in line 6071, saw 19
   ```
2. How to deal with data misplacement? I mean how to make the data shift right two cells with python?

Thanks for your suggestions and here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
import os
WorkingPath = u'E:\\Document'   

os.chdir(WorkingPath)

Shareholder= pd.read_csv(u'./1shareholder/Shareholders.csv', \
                     encoding='utf-16le', delimiter='\t')
```

Comment: Sorry, I mean how to make the data shift left two cells with python?

Comment: You must give more information. Such as, what is `pd.read_csv`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question seems to be about creating and/or reading a CSV file using pandas. To get help with this, you will need to provide a minimal sample of your code that produces this problem.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. We need to see the code that calls `pd.read_csv`. It would also be good to see the CSV data you're parsing, particularly the bad line (line 6071).

Answer (score 0):

If it is a .CSV that means that the entire file is structured as

```
    COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3\n
    1,2,3\n
    A,B,C\n
    Dog,Cat,Bird\n
```

Or a long string that is "COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3\n1,2,3\nA,B,C\nDog,Cat,Bird\n"
You would use a loop to go through it looking for a comma and a new line as delimiters. If you want to shift to the left a couple cells then you need to parse through the csv text and manipulate the commas. So if you need to move a cell 2 to the left you find the number of columns you have, what you want to move to the left, and remove two commas (depending on how you want it to match with your columns) and add them on the right.

In fact, in your image it might not be a misplacement, but rather its possible that the fields that don't have the data for those columns are omitted.
So if you have

```
COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3\n
1,,3\n
A,B,C,D\n
Dog,Bird\n
```

The cell would look like

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3
1       |         | 3
A       | B       | C       | D
Dog     | Bird
```

So the layout would be messed up.

Comment: @MaGrace Do you have a full file that we can all look at? Even if its just the raw text uploaded to gist?

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because the CSV reader encounters lines that are of a different width than the header row (which it assumes to be the first row).

To avoid this, tell it that the data has no header and instead to name the columns based on a numbered range:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None, names=range(20))
```

(Replace 20 with the maximum width of your data.)

If necessary you can later relabel your column headings using `df.columns=...`, and if you need to drop the first row of data (because it contains headings rather than data), use `df = df.drop(0)`.

To shift the misplaced cells to the left, you will need to do something like the following:

```
import numpy as np
...
df.loc[~np.isnan(df[19]), [17, 18]] = df[[19, 20]]
```

This will replace columns 17 and 18 with columns 19 and 20 in rows where the cell in column 19 is not empty.